# How can we log the datas stored in the session into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, session, insert

I'm trying to record the data stored in the session into the database(orderdetails). when there are more than one product, only the first selected product is added, the second product does not register to the database . Is there a problem with the location of foreach or sql3?What could be the reason for this ? I'd appreciate it if you could help.
 
My database ss is here=>>
[image: here]
My code ss is here =>>> 
[image: here]

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
    {
      $sql="INSERT INTO `order` (`orderID`, `tableID`, `orderDate`, `orderStatus`) VALUES (NULL, '".$table_id."', '".$time."', '1')";
      $DBcon -> query($sql);



      foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values){

        $product_id=$values["product_id"];
        $item_name=$values["item_name"];
        $quantity=$values["item_quantity"];
        $product_price=$values["product_price"];
        $pro_sum=$values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"];
        $sql2="SELECT `orderID` FROM `order` WHERE `tableID`='".$table_id."' and `orderStatus`=1";
        $result = $DBcon -> query($sql2);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $order_id = $row['orderID'];
          }            
        }

        $sql3="INSERT INTO `orderdetail` (`orderID`, `productID`, `unitPrice`, `quantity`, `total`) VALUES ('".$order_id."', '".$product_id."', '".$product_price."', '".$quantity."', '".$pro_sum."')";

        if( $DBcon -> query($sql3) === TRUE){
            echo "New record created succesfully.";
         }else{
            echo "Error : " . $sq3l . "<br>" . $DBcon->error;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why the spaces in ```$DBcon -> query($sql3)```?

Comment: Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection and quoting issues.

Comment: can you show us the content of `$_SESSION` after the if?

Comment: @spielerds my checkout.php code is here  =>> https://codeshare.io/Gkzgx4

Comment: But that is only the code. Can you show the content of the variable $_SESSION with more products? Try putting a `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']); exit();` before the foreach and post the results please.

Comment: I added 2 products and insert them in the database. <br>result(array) is here =>>https://image.ibb.co/cErgLJ/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_133.png .<br> but my database have one row :S . =>>https://image.ibb.co/fDPJ0J/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_134.png

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 products and insert them in the database. result(array) is here =>> image.ibb.co/cErgLJ/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_133.png . but my database have one row :S . =>> image.ibb.co/fDPJ0J/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_134.png . I want all products to be stored in rows in the database. but only 1 product table is inserted.